# Odoo methods overriding

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

Here is an example of Odoo method use overriding

```py
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    print "Values: ", vals
    res = super(student_student, self).create(vals)
    print "Result: ", res
    audit_log_data={"user_id":self._uid, 
                    "date":datetime.today(), 
                    "student_info": self.id and (str(self.uni_no) + " " + str(self.name)),
                    "status": "create"}
    # Create a student.audit.log object
    self.env["student.audit.log"].create(audit_log_data)
    return res
```

but why we use overriding here :

```py
res = super(student_student, self).create(vals)
```

In the code, there is no create methods already declared  with the same name this is the first method so why using overriding

Comment: Don't forget that your class is inhering `models.Model` class and the method is declared there.

Comment: ok, so every time we need to use those methods (write, create, copy ...) in odoo we must use overriding? @EasyOdoo

Comment: No when you need to change the default behavior pf the method. We override it

Comment: @EasyOdoo oke thank you, so helpful ;)